# Choosing the material name exporting .mesh files in Ogre

Tags: c++, graphics, textures, ogre

I want to export a .mesh file of my planet with material information.
I'm able to correctly export the .mesh file. But i'm stuck with the code trying to export also the material.
Here's the code i'm using:

```
   Ogre::MaterialPtr matSphere;
        matSphere = Ogre::MaterialManager::getSingleton().create("TexMap", Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME);
        Ogre::Pass *pass = matSphere->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0);
        pass->setLightingEnabled(true);
        pass->setDepthCheckEnabled(true);
        pass->setSceneBlending(Ogre::SBT_TRANSPARENT_ALPHA);

    Ogre::TextureUnitState *tex = pass->createTextureUnitState("MyCustomState", 0);
    tex->setTextureName("PATH\planet.png");
    tex->setTextureFiltering(Ogre::TFO_TRILINEAR);

    matSphere->load();
    // Set texture for the sphere
    sphereEntity->setMaterial(matSphere);

    //Export the shape in a mesh file before destroying it
    Ogre::MeshPtr mesh;
    mesh = sphereEntity->getMesh();
    Ogre::MeshSerializer ser;
    ser.exportMesh(mesh.getPointer(), exportFile,  Ogre::MeshSerializer::ENDIAN_NATIVE);
```

It seems that if i manually create a .material file with no name specifying the material (i mean leaving empty the name of the material), everything works. I've tested this importing the mesh in my program. So the main problem is that when i export a .mesh file, it points to a material with no name. I would like to choose the name of the material.
Here's the project i'm working on: https://github.com/giogix2/PlanetGenerator